# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 65535: unexpected end of data

Tags: python, sockets, unicode, encoding, utf-8

When I use :

```
print(bytes(my_string,'utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
```

everything is okey and I can see my string.

But When I send my_string to another machine, with the following command :

```
conn.send(bytes(my_string,'utf-8'))
```

And receive it in another machine, But When I want to decode it, I get the following error:

```
print(recv_data.decode('utf-8'))

  File "./multiconn-client.py", line 86, in service_connection
    print(recv_data.decode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 65535: unexpected end of data
```

And When I print without encoding :

```
print(recv_data)
```

I see a text But it it is not in my encoding.

How to solve it?

**UPDATE:**

My server :

```
   conn.send(bytes(my_string,'utf-8'))  
   conn.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, sys.getsizeof(my_string))
```

*NOTE:* When I print `my_string` in server everything is OK.

I use selectors module for more than one connection.

In client I use :

```
def service_connection(key, mask):
sock = key.fileobj
data = key.data
if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
    buff = sock.getsockopt(SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVBUF)
    recv_data = sock.recv(1024 | buff)
    if recv_data:
        buff = sock.getsockopt(SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVBUF)
        print('In cli getsizeof of recv_data:',sys.getsizeof(recv_data))
        recv_data += recv_data
        data.recv_total += len(recv_data)
        print(recv_data.decode('utf-8')) #######error line is here.
```

Mow I get the folllowing error only for `decode` function:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./multiconn-client.py", line 122, in <module>
    service_connection(key, mask)
  File "./multiconn-client.py", line 99, in service_connection
    print(recv_data.decode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 65535: invalid continuation byte
```

*NOTE:* When I use `print(recv_data)` without `decode` function, It prints my unicde data such as :

```
b'm01,2,130,12_18,\xd9\x88\xd9\x8e\xd9\x85\xd9\x8e\xd9\x86 \xd9\x8a\xd9\x8e\xd8\xb1\xd9\x92\xd8\xba\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa8\xd9\x8f \xd8\xb9\xd9\x8e\xd9\x86 \xd9\x85\xd9\x91\xd9\x90\xd9\x84\xd9\x91\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa9\xd9\x90 \xd8\xa5\xd9\x90\xd8\xa8\xd9\x92\xd8\xb1\xd9\x8e\xd9\xb0\xd9\x87\xd9\x90\xdb\xa6\xd9\x85\xd9\x8e \xd8\xa5\xd9\x90\xd9\x84\xd9\x91\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa7 \xd9\x85\xd9\x8e\xd9\x86 \xd8\xb3\xd9\x8e\xd9\x81\xd9\x90\xd9\x87\xd9\x8e \xd9\x86\xd9\x8e\xd9\x81\xd9\x92\xd8\xb3\xd9\x8e\xd9\x87\xd9\x8f\xdb\xa5 \xd9\x88\xd9\x8e\xd9\x84\xd9\x8e\xd9\x82\xd9\x8e\xd8\xaf\xd9\x90 \xd9\xb1\xd8\xb5\xd9\x92\xd8\xb7\xd9\x8e\xd9\x81\xd9\x8e\xd9\x8a\xd9\x92\xd9\x86\xd9\x8e\xd9\xb0\xd9\x87\xd9\x8f \xd9\x81\xd9\x90\xd9\x89 \xd9\xb1\xd9\x84\xd8\xaf\xd9\x91\xd9\x8f\xd9\x86\xd9\x92\xd9\x8a\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa7 \xd9\x88\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa5\xd9\x90\xd9\x86\xd9\x91\xd9\x8e\xd9\x87\xd9\x8f\xdb\xa5 \xd9\x81\xd9\x90\xd9\x89 \xd9\xb1\xd9\x84\xd9\x92\xd8\xa1\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa7\xd8\xae\xd9\x90\xd8\xb1\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa9\xd9\x90 \xd9\x84\xd9\x8e\xd9\x85\xd9\x90\xd9\x86\xd9\x8e \xd9\xb1\xd9\x84\xd8\xb5\xd9\x91\xd9\x8e\xd9\xb0\xd9\x84\xd9\x90\xd8\xad\xd9\x90\xd9\x8a\xd9\x86\xd9\x8e#m02,2,238,3_4,\xd8\xad\xd9\x8e\xd9\xb0\xd9\x81\xd9\x90\xd8\xb8\xd9\x8f\xd9\x88\xd8\xa7\xdb\x9f \xd8\xb9\xd9\x8e\xd9\x84\xd9\x8e\xd9\x89 \xd9\xb1\xd9\x84\xd8\xb5\xd9\x91\xd9\x8e\xd9\x84\xd9\x8e\xd9\x88\xd9\x8e\xd9\xb0\xd8\xaa\xd9\x90 \xd9\x88\xd9\x8e\xd9\xb1\xd9\x84\xd8\xb5\xd9\x91\xd9\x8e\xd9\x84\xd9\x8e\xd9\x88\xd9\xb0\xd8\xa9\xd9\x90 \xd9\xb1\xd9\x84\xd9\x92\xd9\x88\xd9\x8f\xd8\xb3\xd9\x92\xd8\xb7\xd9\x8e\xd9\x89\xd9\xb0 \xd9\x88\xd9\x8e\xd9\x82\xd9\x8f\xd9\x88\xd9\x85\xd9\x8f\xd9\x88\xd8\xa7\xdb\x9f \xd9\x84\xd9\x90\xd9\x84\xd9\x91\xd9\x8e\xd9\x87\xd9\x90 \xd9\x82\xd9\x8e\xd9\xb0\xd9\x86\xd9\x90\xd8\xaa\xd9\x90\xd9\x8a\xd9\x86\xd9\x8e#m03,2,277,5_7,\xd8\xa5\xd9\x90\xd9\x86\xd9\x91\xd9\x8e \xd9\xb1\xd9\x84\xd9\x91\xd9\x8e\xd8\xb0\xd9\x90\xd9\x8a\xd9\x86\xd9\x8e \xd8\xa1\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85\xd9\x8e\xd9\x86\xd9\x8f\xd9\x88\xd8\xa7\xdb\x9f \xd9\x88\xd9\x8e\xd8\xb9\xd9\x8e\xd9\x85\xd9\x90\xd9\x84\xd9\x8f\xd9\x88\xd8\xa7\xdb\x9f \xd9\xb1\xd9\x84\xd8\xb5\xd9\x91\xd9\x8e\xd9\xb0\xd9\x84\xd9\x90\xd8\xad\xd9\x8e\xd9\xb0\xd8\xaa\xd9\x90 \xd9\x88\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa3\xd9\x8e\xd9\x82\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85\xd9\x8f\xd9\x88\xd8\xa7\xdb\x9f \xd9\xb1\xd9\x84\xd8\xb5\xd9\x91\xd9\x8e\xd9\x84\xd9\x8e\xd9\x88\xd9\xb0\xd8\xa9\xd9\x8e \xd9\x88\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa1\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa7\xd8\xaa\xd9\x8e\xd9\x88\xd9\x8f\xd8\xa7\xdb\x9f \xd9\xb1\xd9\x84\xd8\xb2\xd9\x91\xd9\x8e\xd9\x83\xd9\x8e\xd9\x88\xd9\xb0\xd8\xa9\xd9\x8e \xd9\x84\xd9\x8e\xd9\x87\xd9\x8f\xd9\x85\xd9\x92 \xd8\xa3\xd9\x8e\xd8\xac\xd9\x92\xd8\xb1\xd9\x8f\xd9\x87\xd9\x8f\xd9\x85\xd9\x92 \xd8\xb9\xd9\x90\xd9\x86\xd8\xaf\xd9\x8e \xd8\xb1\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa8\xd9\x91\xd9\x90\xd9\x87\xd9\x90\xd9\x85\xd9\x92 \xd9\x88\xd9\x8e\xd9\x84\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa7 \xd8\xae\xd9\x8e\xd9\x88\xd9\x92\xd9\x81\xd9\x8c \xd8\xb9\xd9\x8e\xd9\x84\xd9\x8e\xd9\x8a\xd9\x92\xd9\x87\xd9\x90\xd9\x85\xd9\x92 \xd9\x88\xd9\x8e\xd9\x84\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa7 \xd9\x87\xd9\x8f\xd9\x85\xd9\x92 \xd9\x8a\xd9\x8e\xd8\xad\xd9\x92\xd8\xb2\xd9\x8e\xd9\x86\xd9\x8f\xd9\x88\xd9\x86\xd9\x8e#m04,3,39,5_20,\xd9\x81\xd9\x8e\xd9\x86\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa7\xd8\xaf\xd9\x8e\xd8\xaa\xd9\x92\xd9\x87\xd9\x8f \xd9\xb1\xd9\x84\xd9\x92\xd9\x85\xd9\x8e\xd9\x84\xd9\x8e\xd9\xb0\xd9\x93\xd8\xa6\xd9\x90\xd9\x83\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa9\xd9\x8f \xd9\x88\xd9\x8e\xd9\x87\xd9\x8f\xd9\x88\xd9\x8e \xd9\x82\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa7\xd9\x93\xd8\xa6\xd9\x90\xd9\x85\xd9\x8c \xd9\x8a\xd9\x8f\xd8\xb5\xd9\x8e\xd9\x84\xd9\x91\xd9\x90\xd9\x89 \xd9\x81\xd9\x90\xd9\x89 \xd9\xb1\xd9\x84\xd9\x92\xd9\x85\xd9\x90\xd8\xad\xd9\x92\xd8\xb1\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa8\xd9\x90 \xd8\xa3\xd9\x8e\xd9\x86\xd9\x91\xd9\x8e \xd9\xb1\xd9\x84\xd9\x84\xd9\x91\xd9\x8e\xd9\x87\xd9\x8e \xd9\x8a\xd9\x8f\xd8\xa8\xd9\x8e\xd8\xb4\xd9\x91\xd9\x90\xd8\xb1\xd9\x8f\xd9\x83\xd9\x8e \xd8\xa8\xd9\x90\xd9\x8a\xd9\x8e\xd8\xad\xd9\x92\xd9\x8a\xd9\x8e\xd9\x89\xd9\xb0 \xd9\x85\xd9\x8f\xd8\xb5\xd9\x8e\xd8\xaf\xd9\x91\xd9\x90\xd9\x82\xd9\x8b\xdb\xa2\xd8\xa7 \xd8\xa8\xd9\x90\xd9\x83\xd9\x8e\xd9\x84\xd9\x90\xd9\x85\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa9\xd9\x8d \xd9\x85\xd9\x91\xd9\x90\xd9\x86\xd9\x8e \xd9\xb1\xd9\x84\xd9\x84\xd9\x91\xd9\x8e\xd9\x87\xd9\x90 \xd9\x88\xd9\x8e\xd8\xb3\xd9\x8e\xd9\x8a\xd9\x91\xd9\x90\xd8\xaf\xd9\x8b\xd8\xa7 \xd9\x88\xd9\x8e\xd8\xad\xd9\x8e\xd8\xb5\xd9\x8f\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x8b\xd8\xa7 \xd9\x88\xd9\x8e\xd9\x86\xd9\x8e\xd8\xa8\xd9\x90\xd9\x8a\xd9\x91\xd9\x8b\xd8\xa7 \xd9\x85\xd9\x91\xd9\x90\xd9\x86\xd9\x8e \xd9\xb1\xd9\x84\xd8\xb5\xd9\x91\xd9\x8e\xd9\xb0\xd9\x84\xd9\x90\xd8\xad\xd9\x90\xd9\x8a\xd9\x86\xd9\x8e#m05,4,77,39_10,\xd8\xa3\xd9\x8
```

When I comment line `recv_data += recv_data` Error turn into:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 65535: unexpected end of data
```

Comment: is `my_string` massive?

Comment: yes, it's massive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number `65535` is a big red flag.

Have you noticed that 65535 is 2 to the power of 16 minus one? There are 65536 bytes in 64KiB and I'm betting your socket connection doesn't allow you to send more than 64KiB in one go.

Try sending a smaller set of data and see if you have the same problem. If so, you need to figure out how to send the data set in chunks, put them back together at the receiving end and decode the whole.

Comment: Further reading: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/176858/is-there-something-special-about-the-number-65535

Comment: But When I send my data, It sent completely.

Comment: @PersianGulf: it does not matter if the data is __sent__ completely. What matters instead is if the data is __received__ completely. `recv` on a TCP socket is not guaranteed to read all sent data at once since TCP is a byte stream and not a message protocol. Please check the return value of `recv` to find out how many bytes you've actually received and continue to `recv` until you've received the expected number of bytes.

Comment: @PersianGulf, please share your send and receive code as a fully functional example, if you want more help with how to fix your reception. The error you're getting indicates your received data is smaller than what you expect and this could be due to a number of reasons - although I expect Steffen Ulrich to be right and you need to continue receiving until there is nothing more to receive, concatenating the received bytes to construct the whole document.

Comment: @Grismar  , Okey you say true, Can you please guide me to split my packet to chunks? Which size I have to use? for each packet?

Comment: @PersianGulf you probably don't need to specify a specific size, you just send like you already do, but on the receiving end, keep receiving until you reach the end, so receive in a `while` loop or something similar, instead of trying to receive all at once. If you run into trouble doing that, I'd recommend opening a new question on that topic - people will be able to help if you provide a working example.

Comment: It solved at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957363/packet-is-sent-completely-somtimes-and-somtimes-is-not-sent-completely